# iOS: Way to connect two devices using wire

Tags: ios, iphone, usb

I just wondering is there any possible way to connect two iOS devices(iPhones or iPads) over USB wire without MAC/Laptop.

I know I can use something like `usbmuxd` to read my iDevice from MAC/Laptop.
I tried EAAccessory, but seems like it is not designed for reading phones.

What am I missing here?
What about IOKit, does Apple will reject my app if I use it?

Comment: Can you describe the use case here that is not satisfiable by using multipeer connectivity?

Comment: @JoshuaSmith Maybe wire will improve connection reliability. I just curious. I know some ways to connect two devices wirelessly. But I have no idea about wire. I did some research but nothing works.

Comment: You can get certified via the MiFi program but that program is the only way to get access to the wire on an unjailbroken iPhone.